# Passing a dynamically-assigned value into a javascript onclick function

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a Ruby-on-Rails web application in which I need to pass a variable in to a javascript function.  Easy enough if I just want to do something like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:show_details('section_1')">Show Details</a>
```

However, what I need to do is something like this:

```
<% 4.times do |n| %>
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:show_details('section_" + n + "')">Show Details</a>
<% end %>
```

Where the parameter being passed to show_details would resolve to 'section_1' then 'section_2' then 'section_3' and finally 'section_4'

I assume this is probably pretty easy but so far I'm kind of stuck.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have an `<%= %>` thing in rails. If yes, this will work: `<a href="#" onclick="javascript:show_details('section_<%= n %>')">Show Details</a>`

Comment: Thanks - I think that will work.  For some reason I'm not seeing an 'accept' icon next to your answer.  Do you know if I need to do anything to see the icon?

Comment: I posted it only as a comment (and not as an answer) since I wasn't sure if my suggestion would work (i haven't worked with rails).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is this:

```
<% 4.times do |n| %>
  <a href="#" onclick="javascript:show_details('section_<%= n %>')">Show Details</a>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have create Javascript variable for that and increment that variable try this code:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
var count = 1;

function sectionCall(){
show_details('section_'+count);
count+=1;
}

<% end %>



<a href="#" onclick="javascript:sectionCall()">Show Details</a>
```